# Flutter unit test - How to test that an access to a field throws a LateInitializationError

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, dart-null-safety

I want to test a class where a late field is not yet initialized.

Here is the code of my test:

```dart
test('Set lang method', ()  {
    // Throws an exception because the field osLang is not supposed to be initialized yet.
    expect(() => dbRepository.osLang, throwsException); 
    dbRepository.setOsLang('fr');
    expect(dbRepository.osLang, 'fr');
});
```

Unfortunately, I get this error when I run my test:

```
package:test_api                                           expect
package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart 455:16         expect
test/src/models/repositories/db_repository_test.dart 20:7  main.<fn>.<fn>

Expected: throws <Instance of 'Exception'>
  Actual: <Closure: () => String>
   Which: threw LateError:<LateInitializationError: Field '_osLang@19447861' has not been initialized.>
          stack package:my_app/src/models/repositories/db_repository.dart        DBRepository._osLang
                package:my_app/src/models/repositories/db_repository.dart 18:24  DBRepository.osLang
                test/src/models/repositories/db_repository_test.dart 20:33       main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>
                package:test_api                                                 expect
                package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart 455:16               expect
                test/src/models/repositories/db_repository_test.dart 20:7        main.<fn>.<fn>
                
          which is not an instance of 'Exception'
```

I tried to change the `throwsException` with `throwsA(isA<LateInitializationError>)` but my IDE doesn't find any class called `LateInitializationError`.

I can't find a solution to that problem on the flutter documentation.

Comment: `Error`s aren't `Exception`s, so `throwsException` won't work. `isA<LateInitializationError>` is the wrong syntax; it should be `isA<LateInitializationError>()`.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks for your answer, but as I said, I can't import LateInitializationError.. Android studio can't find that class. `Error: 'LateInitializationError' isn't a type.` So I can't import it.

Comment: Hm, `LateInitializationError` *used* to be a public type, but it seems that it isn't public anymore.  You can resort to `throwsA(isA<Error>())`.  IMO testing for `LateInitializationError` seems a bit questionable anyway.  Ideally uninitialized `late` variables shouldn't be exposed, or if your code must require an explicit initialization step, an explicit check for that with a descriptive error message would be better than a confusing `LateInitializationError`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Error`s aren't `Exception`s, so [`throwsException`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-test_api_expect/throwsException-constant.html) won't match it.

`LateInitializationError` *used* to be a public type, but it seems that it isn't public anymore.  You could resort to `throwsA(isA<Error>())`. (Based on the [last available public documentation for it](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.0/dart-core/LateInitializationError-class.html), it derives directly from `Error`, so there isn't a more specific type to test against.) You could check the `Error` string to be more specific:

```dart
expect(
  () => dbRepository.osLang,
  throwsA(
    predicate<Error>(
      (error) => error.toString().contains('LateInitializationError'),
    ),
  ),
);
```

All that said, in my opinion, testing for `LateInitializationError` might be a bit questionable anyway.  Ideally `late` variables shouldn't be exposed as part of your API.  If your code requires an explicit initialization step, then it'd be clearer to have an explicit check with a descriptive error message.  That is, instead of:

```dart
late final String someProperty;
```

you could have something like:

```dart
String? _someProperty;

String get someProperty {
  var _someProperty = this._someProperty;
  if (_someProperty == null) {
    throw StateError('init() must be called first');
  }
  return _someProperty;
}
```